# Issue in converting an Angular 8 app to Android using Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am trying to convert my existing Angular 8 app to an android app using Cordova.I am following this  [tutorial](https://medium.com/@christof.thalmann/convert-angular-project-to-android-apk-in-10-steps-c49e2fddd29).

But, I am getting a white screen when I install the signed and release build in a Android device.Any suggestion?

Comment: What about a debug version? Can you install and run it successfully in debug mode?

Comment: post logs......

Comment: @KaloyanDimitrov I can install the app ,even cordova run browser works fine (i can see the app being rendered) .In emulator as well  it shows a white screen

Comment: @Abx are you listening to the deviceready event to bootstrap your app? If cordova is not improrted properly you might not have the event firing and the app wont start at all which would look like a white screen. How does your index.html look like and also the part where Angular is getting bootstraped? If you are still having this problem you need to provide some more information. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps work for me

1. Install cordova globally
2. Go into the Angular project folder and run this
   `cordova create mobile`
3. If there is not a folder inside your Angular project 
   folder called "dist", run this:
   `ng build`
4. Change directory
   `cd mobile`
5. Link the dist file with the www file. Run this command in cmd
   as administrator
   `mklink /d "C:\Users\....\www" "C:\Users\....\dist"`
6. Go to the parent directory (you should be in the Angular
   project folder now) and run this:
   `ng build`
7. Go to mobile\www\index.html and do this change
   `<base href="/">  -->  <base href="./">`
8. Go to the mobile directory (cd mobile) and run this
   `cordova platform add android`
9. Connect the android phone and run this
   `cordova run android`